# Filter Data before a date and time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am begginer using PHP and MSQL and I can not filter the results of my table correctly. I want to show me all the fields in the table that keep the condition that there are still two hours for the date and time I have stored.

I used this query but does not work well, because if the current month is 12 and is stored in the DB 1 is not shown, as if even the time stored is less than 2 hours even another day:

```
 putenv('TZ=Europe/Madrid'); 

 $anoE = date("y");
 $mesE =  date("m");
 $diaE =  date("d");

 $horaE = date("H");
 ...

 $consulta = "SELECT tipo,nombre,descripcion,hora,minuto ,lugar,duracion,fecha,horacero,id,ano,dia,mes,equipo FROM ".$tabla." WHERE ".$anoE." <= `ano` AND ".$mesE." <= `mes` AND ".$diaE." <= `dia` AND ".$horaE." <= `(hora+2)` ORDER BY ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto";
```

I don't know how i can write the while condition for the query shows fields which remain them two hours beyond the current time (same day)

Comment: Can you add a column to the db to store the date in DATETIME (`YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss`) format? That's probably easiest & most accurate.

Comment: Ok,i will add that column, but how do I make the condition that remain two hours?

Comment: I think that i can use something as TIMESTAMPDIFF.

Comment: Yep, or do the math in PHP like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 2*60*60)`

Answer (score 0):

If your field type is `DATETIME` (*if not, make it*) you can use simple query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE datetime_field_name BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND NOW()
```

Which will select all records that are between `now - 2 hours` and `now`.